# Asp.net MVC 5 controller from another assembly serving angular static file miss js and css

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, iis

I have a project that contains the UI and a class library where I have shared views.

I'm using VirtualPathProvider to serve Razor pages as embedded resources and it works fine.

But on it class library now I have a angular app, ant it view.

I serve the static html file from angular using a MVC controller and it worked fine. The only one issue is the js and css files are missing because they are referenced as relative path in the same folder level of index.html, but the static files requests are not handled by Asp.Net pipeline.

Some similar questions sujest to use `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` to catch the static files request, but it didn't work for me
.
I put the config on my web.config like

```
<add name="scripts" path="/controller/action/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it to use a razor index where I put all references to the scripts using @Script.Render method, so it solve the problem to request the files.